# DRY instance variables for similar find queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, dry

Perhaps this question may have already been answered, but I am not sure what to search for.

I have a page with an A to Z list of clothing brands, which has an each block to iterate through them all. I would like to split this list out by letter, and have an A to Z row of links at the top, where each letter jumps down the page to their letter in the list. In order to do this however, I can only think of making an each loop for each letter, with `<A NAME="A">` etc. next to it, and an instance variable for each one.

My question is, how do I avoid having 26 different instance variables in my controller?

```
@Abrands = Product.where('brand LIKE ?', "A%")
@Bbrands = Product.where('brand LIKE ?', "B%")
@Cbrands = Product.where('brand LIKE ?', "C%")
etc.
```

This is clearly not very DRY, is there a better way I could do this? I am still finding my feet with rails, any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like this work for you?

```
@products = Product.all.group_by{|product| product.brand.slice(0,1)}
```

This is a nice one-liner that will only issue 1 query.  It will result in a hash similar to other users' suggestions.

Comment: Wow, yes! I wasn't expecting such a neat piece of code, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
# Hash initialization to empty arrays
@brands = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }

Product.all.each do |product|
  @brands[product.brand[0].upcase.to_sym] << product
end
```

which returns a hash like this:

```
{:A => [products for brands A*], :B => [products for brands B*], ...}
```

This method has the advantage of doing only one query instead of 26.

Comment: do you mean `@brands = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }`? Otherwise, all your lists are the same instance and will contain all products in the end. Or am I missing something?

Comment: you're right, I believed it would spawn a new copy of the array. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 0):

Does this openrailscasts episode help you?
[Non Active Record (Products by Letter)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/121-non-active-record-model)